# Is it possible to run Google Spreadsheet Add-On for not signed-in users?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've built an add-on for Google spreadsheets. Its a simple chat that runs in Sidebar, it uses CacheService (public cache) for storing messages. It works great for collaborators, but it doesnt show up for not logged-in users. Actually, even a custom Menu item doesnt show up. It is still in development and is not published, it is bound to the Spreadsheet. So is it possible to run it without user signing in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an official answer, but i highly doubt this will be available.
I assume you have the spreadsheet shared as 'public with anonymous write'.
Apps scripts have quotas and they are deducted from the active user. If there is no active user i doubt google will allow that.
There are other ways to let anonymous usera runs scripts, like a gas service published to run as the owner (not active user) but those are for web apps and not for addons or code that runs inside the spreadsheet (menus triggers etc)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to find what you're looking for here

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle